# Batching threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm updating some existing code that looks like this:

```
for i in list
  thread.start_new_thread(main, (i[0],i[1],i[2],2))
```

This causes threads to be created for every item in the list, but not executed until all the threads are created. I'd like to either execute the threads in small groups, or just have them execute directly after they're created.

(There are a lot of python threads discussion on here so sorry if I missed this type of question already being asked...)

Comment: `start_new_thread` as its name suggests starts new thread immediately. Note `thread` module had been deprecated by `threading` module since 2005.

Answer (score 4):

You may find the [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) module useful. It's available also for Python 2 under the name [`futures`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures/2.1.3). For example, to invoke a function `main` for every item on `MY_LIST` concurrently, but with at most 5 threads, you can write:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for result in executor.map(main, MY_LIST):
        # Do something with result
        print(result)
```

Comment: This worked pretty well actually. I feel I should be able to implement this in native code. No?